# mojarra is not defined

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I'm developing JSF application with mojarra.

I'm getting javascript error "mojarra is not defined".

After deploy everything is ok, ajax call works properly. 
But after refreshing page, error appears.

There is lack of javascript include in head tag after refreshing.

It seems to be working very moody.

Same behavior I have on Tomcat and Glassfish, Mojarra is in version 2.0.3.

Comment: do you have <h:head></h:head> in your page? also take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9263184/617373

Comment: It seems that Eclipse project error. After moving sources to new project, everything is working fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reason this error can appear is by using `<head>..</head>` and `<body>...</body>` tags instead of `<h:head>...</h:head>` and `<h:body>...</h:body>`.

Namespace - `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"`