# PrimeFaces: How do I declare and bind an AJAX "rowEdit" event to p:dataTable programmatically?

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I'm still developing my data table UI application, and finally I'm about the final stage of the development of this component: inline cell editing.

First of all, the data table is built fully dynamically at the Java side, and no facelet declarations are used to describe the table. If I'd have a static table declaration, the editing could be specified [like this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableEditing.jsf) (see the In-Cell Editing chapter):

```xml
<p:dataTable>
    ...
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}"/>  
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

I can easily specify the data table editable with `dataTable.setEditable(true)` in the Java code - and it works, please note, the editing Save/Cancel icons are working nice but have no effect at the back end. Since I cannot it declare in the way specified at the PF ShowCase Labs page (must I always use the listeners there?) because of the data tables are rendered dynamically, I'm trying to use the following:

```java
public static AjaxBehavior createAjaxBehavior(MethodExpression expression) {
    final AjaxBehavior behavior = new AjaxBehavior();
    behavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(expression));
    return behavior;
}
...
dataTable.addClientBehavior("rowEdit", createAjaxBehavior(createMethodExpression(TableBean.class, "onEdit", void.class, new Class<?>[] {RowEditEvent.class})));
```

But as soon as I add the `rowEdit` listener, like I'm trying to do above, and wow I suddenly got: `mojarra is not defined` and no Save/Cancel row edit buttons are working. Ok, I've found a similar problem described and resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263184/166589), included the necessary script manually, and now the client-side JavaScript error is gone, however *I still cannot exit the row editing mode, and the row is still not updated*.

I wasted all day trying to figure out what's going on, and I'm blind to see the correct way. Do I simply miss something behind (like *identifying a certain row*, or probably *specifying something else somewhere* -- but my Java code does not generate anything more than specified in the PF example), or anything whatever?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at showcase-labs Editable Datatable [source code](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/webapp/ui/datatableEditing.xhtml) or source from [demo page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableEditing.jsf)?

Comment: @FlavioCysne, sure, this is where my dynamic code is inspired from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've just figured out the real reason in the following method:

```java
public static AjaxBehavior createAjaxBehavior(MethodExpression expression) {
    final AjaxBehavior behavior = new AjaxBehavior();
    behavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(expression));
    return behavior;
}
```

In fact, the method actually returned `javax.faces.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior (h:ajax?)` instead of `org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehavior (p:ajax)` -- this happened because of quick auto-complete so I simply missed that fact.

I'm frustrated that the PrimeFaces library didn't reply any error.

---

Just to complete the Q & A:

- Mojarra 2.1.7
- PrimeFaces 3.2

Answer (score -1):

Should now (at least for PF 6.0) be `org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehavior`.

Comment: Hi, I've just edited your answer and didn't downvote, but it's more like a comment to a question/answer, and not a real answer. Thanks.