# commandLink does not invoke action listener, but commandButton works fine

Tags: jsf-2, commandlink

I want to invoke one method through a link from Facelets:

My Facelets code is like:

```
<h:commandButton value="A" actionListener="#{customerData.searchedCustomerListA}" />

<h:commandLink value="A" actionListener="#{customerData.searchedCustomerListA}"/>
```

Backing bean code is like:

```
public void searchedCustomerListA(ActionEvent ae){
    customerName = "A";
    leftCustomerListAvailable.clear();
    if(customerDataBean.getSearchedCustomerList(customerName)!= null)
        leftCustomerListAvailable =customerDataBean.getSearchedCustomerList("A");
}
```

The same code is working for `<h:commandButton>` but not working for `<h:commandLink>`. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you see any errors in JavaScript console in browser when clicking on `commandLink`?

Comment: Try to use `action` instead of `actionListener`.

Comment: Hi pepuch, I tried with action also, but not getting the result.

Answer (score 3):

The technical difference between `<h:commandLink>` and `<h:commandButton>` is that the link uses JavaScript to submit the parent form. So if it doesn't work while a syntactically equivalent button works fine, then that can only mean that either JavaScript is disabled in browser, or that the `jsf.js` file containing the mandatory helper functions isn't included in the page (which you should easily have noticed by seeing JS errors in the JS console of browser's builtin developer toolset).

So, to fix this problem, you need to verify if JS is enabled in browser and that you've a `<h:head>` component instead of plain HTML `<head>` in the template, so that JSF will be able to auto-include the `jsf.js` file.

Or, if your application's business requirements requires that the application functions as designed with JS disabled, then you should stick to `<h:commandButton>` and throw in some CSS to make it to look like a link (e.g. remove background, padding, border, inset, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This sould work.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form>

    <h:commandLink type="button" action="#{testBean.tsetLink}"> 
          <h:outputText value="A" />
    </h:commandLink>

</h:form>
</html>
```

## ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {

    public void tsetLink(){
    System.out.println("Link clicked!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi neni, I tried with your solution. But still not getting the result. also I tried action instead of actionListener. but the result is same.

Comment: is it problem with JSF version ?

Comment: Which version of JSF you are using? Are you using any component libraries like primefaces, rich faces?

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0 . am not using any external component libraries.

Comment: do you have the commandLink inside a form? See my updated answer, It is working fine I have tested it on my machine.

Comment: @ArkaBhaduri any solutions  please  I am  facing  same  problem as  u :/

Answer (score 0):

I my case the cause of this issue was a poorly configured url rewriting filter. One of the filters patterns unintentionally matched `http://localhost:8080/mysite/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces` which prevented jsf.js from being loaded. Check this answer: [Clicking h:commandLink causes Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248047/mojarra-is-not-defined-commandlink-not-making-a-request/9263184#9263184).