# javax.faces:jsf.js resource returns 404

Tags: jsf

I currently use mojarra javax.faces-2.2.8.jar and Apache Tomcat 6.0.26 Server.

I'm trying to add ajax behaviour to an input field(it's just for simplification).

Here is the simple facelets page(welcome.xhtml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:al = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/AppearanceLibrary" 
      xmlns:h = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:ui = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for = "login" 
                       value = "login" />
            <h:inputText id = "login" value = "#{authentication.submittedLogin}">
                <f:ajax execute = "login" render = "out" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputText id = "out" value = "#{authentication.submittedLogin}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the HTML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2"><script type="text/javascript" src="/JSFCars/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script></head><body>
<form id="j_idt4" name="j_idt4" method="post" action="/JSFCars/welcome.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt4" value="j_idt4" />
<label for="j_idt4:login">login</label><input id="j_idt4:login" type="text" name="j_idt4:login" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','j_idt4:login','j_idt4:out')" /><span id="j_idt4:out"></span><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="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" autocomplete="off" />
</form></body>
</html>
```

This is my deployment descriptor:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                               http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         id = "WebApp_ID" 
         version = "3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD
        </param-name>
        <param-value>
            client
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
        </param-name>
        <param-value>
            resources.application
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Inside the browser's JavaScript console I got the message that this request http://localhost:8086/JSFCars/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development failed with 404(Not found). And as the result when I try to invoke the  input field's ajax behaviour I get the following message: Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined.

I'm aware that I should use `<h:head>` and `<h:body>`, otherwise the jsf.js wasn't included in first place. I've tried several browsers and the results were the same. Also I've tried the myfaces-core-2.0.2-bin jsf implementation.

I has found very similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248047/clicking-hcommandlink-causes-uncaught-referenceerror-mojarra-is-not-defined) The problem was connected with the user defined filter which rejected the js request. But I
 don't define any filters in the web deployment descriptor. Might there be any implicitly defined filter that blocks that request? Or are there any other ideas why something blocks that request?

Since the time I asked this question I installed "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.2" 
server and deployed the application on it(I included "javax.faces-2.2.8.jar" into project libraries, 
but I think the server uses the internal "Mojarra 2.2.14" JSF implementation). As the way of testing 
of the JSF implementation I tried using a template, a composite componet. `<ui:composition>`, `<ui:define>` 
tags and custom library inclusion work as needed. `authentication` bean is created and perfectly initialized using `faces-congig.xml`. Then after it I removed everything not related to 
the question and left only `welcome.xhtml` page. Again I got "404 Not found".

The solution is to remove everything connected to faces servlet from the `web.xml`.

[The view of the rendered `welcome.xhtml` page after applying the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uo2U.jpg)

Comment: can we have a look at your `web.xml` file?

Comment: @Kaizen , I edited my question and added information of the `web.xml`.

Comment: @Kaizen, thank you for your contribution, I've already got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

is very weird.... This would mean nothing but your welcome page is loaded via the Faces servlet. So the jsf.js which has an .xhtml extension in the name as well as you posted yourself isn't either. Fix the url pattern (or remove all the faces servlet references since the defaults are most often fine) and everything will work

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I erroneously decided that I should map all facelets pages to the faces servlet. Now I've changed the url pattern to `<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>`. Now the browser returns blank page on the `welcome.xhtml` request.. From the browser's console I see that the server returned the source code for the `welcome.xhtml`.

Comment: just remove all faces servlet thingsro, the web.xml. defaults should be fine

Comment: everything works perfectly and as expected! Thank you so much! :)